# scene detection with node-fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I try to detect when a scene is changing in video.

I use in command line

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo" -f null - 2> ffout
```

But I want to do it with `node-fluent-ffmpeg`.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this (at least for thumbnails) working like so:

```
 const command = ffmpeg('./file.mp4')
    .outputOptions([
        "-vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)'",
        "-vsync vfr"
    ])
    .output('%05d.png')
    .on('end', () => console.log('done'))
    .run();
```